# Checking collision for each cube in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I'm trying to check collision for each cube in arraylist, but the result is, that collision is working only for last cube in arraylist..

```
public class Cube {

    public int x, y;
    private boolean conflict = false;

    public Cube(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        if(!conflict("down")) {
            this.y += 18;
        }
    }

    public boolean conflict(String dir) {
        if(dir.equals("down")) {
            for(Cube cubes : Panel.cubes) {
                if(this.hashCode() != cubes.hashCode()) {
                    if(this.y + 18 == cubes.y && this.x == cubes.x || this.y >= Main.height - 18*4) {
                        this.conflict = true;
                    } else this.conflict = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your conflict method doesn't `return` anything, I'm wondering how this compiles.  But the problem is you never go out the `for loop` when you find a collision.

```
public boolean conflict(String dir) {
    if (dir.equals("down")) {
        for(Cube cubes : Panel.cubes) {
            if(this.hashCode() != cubes.hashCode()) {
                if(this.y + 18 == cubes.y && this.x == cubes.x || this.y >= Main.height - 18*4) {
                    this.conflict = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.conflict = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return this.conflict;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's works! :)) I forget to copy return from my code, but it was there :P

Comment: @mcfly24 you're welcome :) don't forget to put one of the answers as answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to break from the loop when you find a conflict, since otherwise the next iteration may reset that flag (which explains why "collision is working only for last cube in arraylist").

```
    if (dir.equals("down")) {
        for(Cube cubes : Panel.cubes) {
            if(this.hashCode() != cubes.hashCode()) {
                if(this.y + 18 == cubes.y && this.x == cubes.x || this.y >= Main.height - 18*4) {
                    this.conflict = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.conflict = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW, your `conflict` method seems to be missing a return statement.

Comment: @Lino well, since the return statement was missing from the original code, I preferred not to make an assumption. Perhaps the actual method was changed to a `void` method (which only updates `this.conflict` instead of returning a boolean).